# How to decode password from sys.syslogins table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, security, sql-server-2008

I have a program in which the user needs to login with user name and password.
I'm checking the name from the `sys.syslogins` table in master db.
But for the password I receive a string with (probably) coded characters like this (1?????????????).
Now what can I do in order to decode that string and take the password in order to compare with the enter it one?

Comment: A secure password system won't allow you to decode a password. You check passwords by encoding the one you want to test and comparing to see if they're equal.

Comment: Yes Mark by using the proposal of dear Gonzalo

Comment: Gonzalo is doing exactly what Mark said... He's comparing the encoded values of a known password with the existing encoded values. It's not decoding the password from syslogins.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT name FROM sys.syslogins
WHERE pwdcompare('somepassword', password) = 1
```

**Edited** to replace double quotes with single quotes.

Comment: Dear Gonzalo I want to thank you very much, and say to you that your answer was the only accurate, with one deference, in the somepassword we don't use the double quote (") but we have to use the single quote ('), thank you very much you where grate.

Comment: cool!  i've always hashed in the code, not that database side.  Does MySQL have something like this?

Comment: Yes, in MySql you do: SELECT user FROM user WHERE password = PASSWORD('YOURPASSWORD');

Answer (score 8):

You can't decode sys.syslogins: it's a one way hash.

You compare like for like if it uses the same technique or run it through [pwdcompare](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd822792.aspx)

Note: it's also [sys.sql_logins](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174355%28SQL.90%29.aspx) in SQL Server 2005+

Also, why would you use SQL Server logins to validate a user? It doesn't make sense...